# When is upstream_addr a "-" in nginx access log of a load balancer?

Tags: nginx

I set up a load balancer using proxy_pass and upstream.

Then in access log most of upstream_addr are normal upstream ip address, however I got some "-" in nginx access log for upstream_addr.  So when will that happen? Why is it empty?

Comment: The access log shows a `-` when the variable is empty.

Comment: @RichardSmith I set up a load balancer using proxy_pass and upstream,  most of upstream_addr are normal upstream ip address ,so in what situation this variable is empty? Thanks.